# Numpy atleast_1d, but for lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy

I have a function that takes as an argument either a list of objects or a single object. I then want to loop through the elements of the list or operate on the single object if it is not a list.

Below, I use `numpy.atleast_1d().tolist()` to ensure that a loop works whether or not the argument is a list or a single object. However, I am not sure if converting the object to a `numpy` array and then to a list may cause any unintended changes to the object.

Is there a way to ensure the argument is transformed into a list if it is not a list? I have two possible solutions in a simple example below, but wanted to know if there are any better ones.

```
import numpy as np

def printer1(x):
    for xi in np.atleast_1d(x).tolist():
        print(xi)

def printer2(x):
    if type(x) != list:
        x = [x]

    for xi in x:
        print(xi)

x1 = 'a'
x2 = ['a','b','c']

printer1(x1)
printer1(x2)

printer2(x1)
printer2(x2)
```

I'm using `Python 2.7`

Comment: Have a look into the **isinstance()** function.  This returns True/False; if the object is a list, perform your list loop; else operate on the single object.  Sorry for poor formatting, I'm using my phone.  Will add code as an answer later if you're interested.

Comment: I like both of these, and maybe slightly prefer the second approach. I can't think of any bad consequences of using `np.atleast_1d()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your function you can add check for array. I think this is one way to do it. You dont even need to use `numpy` for this.

```
def foo(x):
  x = [x] if not isinstance(x, list) else x
  printx # or do whatever you want to do
  # or
  for value in x:
    print value


foo('a')
foo(['a','b'])
```

**output:**

```
['a']
a
['a', 'b']
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that the element will be a list even that it has only one element, declare its value inside square brackets:

```
foo = ['stringexample']
foo2 = ['a','b']

for foos in foo:
    print(foos)
    
for foos2 in foo2:
    print(foos2)
```

This way, even that 'foo' has only a single string, it will still operate as a list with only one element.

Also, you could try this:

```
declare a empty list 
use youremptylist.extend(incoming value)
```

It will iterate a new list for each incoming value, even that it is a single one

Comment: I'd like the use to be able to enter either a single object or a list of objects, and then handle either case on the backend, within the function.

Comment: Edited, check my second alternative! :)

Comment: Neither method works?

Answer (score 1):

As Roni is saying, you can use this:

```
def printer(x):
  finalList = []
  finalList.extend(x)

  print finalList
```

if x is a single value, it will be added to the `finalList`, if `x` is a list, it will be joined to `finalList` and you can iterate throught it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want loopable things mostly untouched and non loopables behave like a 1-element list you could do something like:

```
def forceiter(x):
    return getattr(x,"__iter__",lambda:(x,))()
```

Demo:

```
for x in [1,[2],range(3),"abc",(),{3:3,4:"x"}, np.logspace(0,3,4)]:
    print(x,end="  -->  ")
    for i in forceiter(x):
        print(i,end=" ")
    print()

# 1  -->  1 
# [2]  -->  2 
# range(0, 3)  -->  0 1 2 
# abc  -->  a b c 
# ()  -->  
# {3: 3, 4: 'x'}  -->  3 4 
# [   1.   10.  100. 1000.]  -->  1.0 10.0 100.0 1000.0
```

Comment: This is nice, but in my case, I'm not getting the behavior I desire. Suppose x can either be a list of dictionaries or one dictionary. And I want to execute a function, f() on each dictionary.

When x is a list of dictionaries, I get the desired behavior: the loop cycles through and executes f() on each dictionary.

However, when x is a single dictionary, I'd like the loop to do one cycle and execute f() on the entire dictionary. In your example, the loop cycles through each key in the dictionary and tries to execute f() on each key.

Comment: @proj Yep, you'll have to use one of the explicitly type checking solutions then. I'll leave this up anyway, maybe some  one else finds it useful.